# Declaring datepart parameter which can be used in DATENAME() function

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql

Is it possible ? I tried a lot of different types of variables but none of them fit , I need it because i have multiple cases and it would be cool if i could write one for all of them .... something like DATENAME(@Someparameter,GETDATE()) 
and parameter would be what type ?

```
DECLARE @Someparameterdate ???????;
SET @Someparameter= CASE @SortOrder 
WHEN '1' THEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())
WHEN '2' THEN DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())
WHEN '3' THEN DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: You could certainly encapsulate it in a [user-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine) (`GetDateNameElement( @Element, @Date )` containing a `case` expression), but the performance may become problematic depending on the usage. [_SWAG_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/SWAG#English): Perhaps if you ask the _real_ question about user-specified sorting of results ... .

Comment: @HABO Will do for further questions , thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use dynamic SQL, that's Impossible.
From Microsoft Docs [`DATENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql) page:

> Arguments
>   datepart
>   Is the part of the date to return. The following table lists all valid datepart arguments. **User-defined variable equivalents are not valid.**

(emphasis mine.)

Same is true for all date/datetime functions involving a datepart argument - it has to be hardcoded.